# Getting object index in django object list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have a list in context of one of my pages called *comments* and when I'm iterating on it i want to know the index of item; i want to know the index of *comment* in this for loop:

```html
<!-- comment list section -->
                <div class="card shadow my-3 p-5">
                    <h3>Comments:</h3>
                <!-- checking if any comment exist on this post -->
                    {% if comments.count < 1 %}
                        No comments. write the first one!
                    {% else %}
                        <!-- iterating on comments and showing them -->
                        {% for comment in comments %}
                            <div id="comment-div">
                                <span id="Comment-name">by: {{ comment.name }}</span>
                                <span id="Comment-date">{{ comment.datetime_created|date:'M d Y' }}</span>
                                <p id="Comment-body">{{ comment.body }}</p>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

view:

```py
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    form_class = CreateComment

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  # get the default context data
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(accepted=True)  # add extra field to the context
        return context
```

model:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=35)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foorloop.counter or forloop.counter0

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {{forloop.counter}} (begins with 1)
  {{forloop.counter0}} (begins at 0)
```

There's some other handy tools as well. Have a look at the docs for ['for' builtins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)